# Не могу вывести даные из текстового файла, запускается консоль и выводиться пустота бесконечно

Tags: c++, visual-c++

мой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Human {
    
public:
    string value;
    string bas = "Basa.txt";
    fstream bass;
    void out () {
        bass.open(bas, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
        while (!bass.eof()) {
            value = "";
            bass << value;
            cout << value << endl;
        }
        
    }
};
class Runmenu {
public:
    void run() {

    }
};

int main(){
    Human test;
    test.out();


}
```

Comment: А что вы хотите?!! У вас в бесконечном цикле — `value = ""; cout << value << endl;`, т.е. просто вывод пустых строк...

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы цикл не был бесконечным?

Comment: А это зависит от того, что вы хотите. Не хотите бесконечный - измените условие...

Comment: @Harry какое условие тогда поставить?

Comment: `bass << value;` - записывает в файл. `bass >> value;` - записывает в строку

Comment: Я же вас спросил самым первым — *а что вы хотите*? Если я вам скажу "напишите `while(0)`" — цикл не будет бесконечным, но разве это вас устроит? Ну не ставится так вопрос! Заметим, *вас  не интересует*, как решить задачу. Вас интересует, как сделать цикл не бесконечным...

Comment: @Harry, я создал этот цикл для того чтобы вывести текстовые данные с файла, я поставил условие пока в файле есть символы, цикл выполняеться, а у меня почему-то цикл игнорирует условие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывод из текстового файла на консоль проще всего организовать так:

```
ifstream in("Bass.txt");
cout << in.rdbuf();
```

Если очень хочется "вручную"...

```
ifstream in("Bass.txt");
for(char c;in.get(c);cout.put(c));
```